# c++ Stuck making an binary tree implementation with an array and lists

Tags: c++, arrays, tree, linked-list

I am working on writing a list of children binary tree implementation. In my code I have an array of lists. Each list contains a node followed by its children on the tree. I finished writing the code and everything compiled, but I keep getting a segmentation fault error and I cannot figure out why. I have been attempting to debug and figure out where my code messes up. I know that there is an issue with the FIRST function. It causes a segmentation fault. Also, when I try to print just one of the lists of the array, it prints everything. I have been stuck on this for a very long time now and would like some help. Can anyone offer suggestions as to why the FIRST and PRINT functions are not working? Maybe there is a large error that I just cannot see.

My code is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <array>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

struct node
{
   char element;
   struct node *next;
}*start;

class list
{
   public:
      void ADD(char n);
      node* CREATE(char n);
      void BEGIN(char n);
      char FIRST();
      char END();
      char NEXT(char n);
      char PREVIOUS(char n);
      int LOCATE(char n);
      void EMPTY();
      void PRINT();
      list()
      {
         start = NULL;
      }
};

char PARENT(const char n, list tree[], int length)
{
   int i=0;
   list l;
   for (i; i<length; i++)
   {
      l = tree[i];
      if (n != l.FIRST())
      {
         if (l.LOCATE(n)>0)
            return l.FIRST();
      }
   }
}

char LEFTMOST_CHILD(char n, list tree[], int length)
{
   int i;
   list l;
   for (i=0; i<length; i++)
   {
      l = tree[i];
      if (l.FIRST() == n)
         return l.NEXT(n);
   }
}

char RIGHT_SIBLING(char n, list tree[], int length)
{
   int i;
   list l;
   for (i=0; i<length; i++)
   {
      l = tree[i];
      if(n != l.FIRST())
      {
      if (l.LOCATE(n) > 0)
         {
            return l.NEXT(n);
         }
      }
   }
}

char ROOT(list tree[]) //assumes array is in order, root is first item
{
   list l;
   l = tree[0];
   cout << "Assigned tree to l" << endl;
   return l.FIRST();
}

void MAKENULL(list tree[], int length)
{
   int i;
   list l;
   for (i=0; i<length; i++)
   {
      l = tree[i];
      l.EMPTY();
   }
}

void list::PRINT()
{
   struct node *temp;
   if (start == NULL)
   {
      cout << "The list is empty" << endl;
      return;
   }
   temp = start;
   cout << "The list is: " << endl;
   while (temp != NULL)
   {
      cout << temp->element << "->" ;
      temp = temp->next;
   }
   cout << "NULL" << endl << endl;
}

void list::EMPTY()
{
   struct node *s, *n;
   s = start;
   while (s != NULL)
   {
      n = s->next;
      free(s);
      s = n;
   }  
   start = NULL;
}

int list::LOCATE(char n)
{
   int pos = 0;
   bool flag = false;
   struct node *s;
   s = start;
   while (s != NULL)
   {
      pos++;
      if (s->element == n)
      {
         flag == true;
         return pos;
      }
      s = s->next;
   }
   if (!flag)
      return -1;
}
void list::ADD(char n)
{
   struct node *temp, *s;
   temp = CREATE(n);
   s = start;
   while (s->next != NULL)
      s = s->next;
   temp->next = NULL;
   s->next = temp;
}

node *list::CREATE(char n)
{
   struct node *temp;
   temp = new(struct node);
   temp->element = n;
   temp->next = NULL;
   return temp;
}

void list::BEGIN(char n)
{
   struct node *temp, *p;
   temp = CREATE(n);
   if (start == NULL)
   {
      start = temp;
      start->next = NULL;
   }
}

char list::FIRST()
{
   char n;
   struct node *s;
   s = start;
   cout << "s = start" << endl;
   n = s->element;
   cout << "n" << endl;
   return n;
}
char list::END()
{
   struct node *s;
   s = start;
   int n;
   while (s != NULL)
   {
      n = s->element;
      s = s->next;
   }
   return n;
}

char list::NEXT(char n)
{
   char next;
   struct node *s;
   s = start;
   while (s != NULL)
   {
      if (s->element == n)
         break;
      s = s->next;
   }
   s = s->next;
   next = s->element;
   return next;
}
char list::PREVIOUS(char n)
{
   char previous;
   struct node *s;
   s = start;
   while (s != NULL)
   {
      previous = s->element;
      s = s->next;
      if (s->element == n)
         break;
   }
   return previous;
}
main()
{
   list a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n;
   a.BEGIN('A');
   b.BEGIN('B');
   c.BEGIN('C');
   d.BEGIN('D');
   e.BEGIN('E');
   f.BEGIN('F');
   g.BEGIN('G');
   h.BEGIN('H');
   i.BEGIN('I');
   j.BEGIN('J');
   k.BEGIN('K');
   l.BEGIN('L');
   m.BEGIN('M');
   n.BEGIN('N');
   a.ADD('B');
   a.ADD('C');
   b.ADD('D');
   b.ADD('E');
   e.ADD('I');
   i.ADD('M');
   i.ADD('N');
   c.ADD('F');
   c.ADD('G');
   c.ADD('H');
   g.ADD('J');
   g.ADD('K');
   h.ADD('L');
   a.PRINT();
   list tree[] = {a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n};
   int length = sizeof(tree)/sizeof(char);

   char root = ROOT(tree);
   cout << "Found root" << endl;
   char parent = PARENT('G', tree, length);
   cout << "Found Parent" << endl;
   char leftChild = LEFTMOST_CHILD('C', tree, length);
   cout << "found left child" << endl;
   char rightSibling = RIGHT_SIBLING('D', tree, length);
   cout << "found right sibling" << endl;

   cout << "The root of the tree is: ";
   cout << root << endl;
   cout << "The parent of G is: ";
   cout << parent << endl;
   cout << "The leftmost child of C is" ;
   cout << leftChild << endl;
   cout << "The right sibling of D is: " ;
   cout << rightSibling << endl;
}
```

Any help will be very appreciated. Thanks you!

Comment: Why? Linked lists don't have anything to do with trees. You can either use an array or a linked *tree*. Unclear what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The fundamental problem is that you have written a lot of code before testing any of it. When you write code, start with something small and simple that works perfectly, add complexity a little at a time, test at every step, and **never add to code that doesn't work.**

The specific problem (or at least one fatal problem) is here:

```
struct node
{
  char element;
  struct node *next;
}*start;

class list
{
public:
  //...
  list()
  {
    start = NULL;
  }
};
```

The variable `start` is a *global* variable. The class `list` has no member variables, but uses the global variable. It sets `start` to NULL every time a `list` is constructed, and every `list` messes with the same pointer. The function `FIRST` dereferences a pointer without checking whether the pointer is NULL, and when it is, you get Undefined Behavior.

It's not entirely clear what you intended, but you seem to misunderstand how variables work in C++.